# Transcoding & displaying user-uploaded videos for cross-browser/platform compatibility

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, flv, jwplayer

I want to display user-uploaded videos in high quality on different browsers/platforms. I think I have a pretty good start, but there are a few issues. I have at my disposal ffmpeg 0.10 (called from PHP) and jwPlayer 5.8 (licensed).

Ideally I would like to support:

- Browsers with Flash 9+
- Modern Firefox/Chrome/Safari without Flash
- iOS 4.1+
- Android 2.2+

My current transcoding commands are:

```
$commands = array(
    'flv' => "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i {$sourceFile} -b 500k -ar 22050 -ab 64 {$tmpFileName}.flv 2>&1",
    'webm' => "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i {$sourceFile} -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 500k {$tmpFileName}.webm 2>&1",
    'mp4' => "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i {$sourceFile} -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -level 21 -refs 2 -vf 'scale=trunc(ih*a/2)*2:trunc(iw/a/2)*2' -b 500k -bt 1000k -threads 0 -f mp4 {$tmpFileName}.pre.mp4 2>&1",
    'jpg' => "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i {$sourceFile} -ss 5 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo {$tmpFileName}.jpg 2>&1"
);

$fastStartCommand = "/usr/bin/qt-faststart {$tmpFileName}.pre.mp4 {$tmpFileName}.mp4");
```

My current display code is this:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" poster="{$fileJPG}" style="width: {$width}px; height: {$height}px;">
    <source src="{$fileMP4}" type="video/mp4" data-ext="mp4" />
    <source src="{$fileWEBM}" type="video/webm" data-ext="webm" />
    <a href="{$fileMP4}" title="Play Video">
        <img border="0" src="{$fileJPG}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" alt="Play Video" />
    </a>
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF(
    '/flash/jwPlayer.swf',
    'video',
    {$width},
    {$height},
    '9.0.0',
    '',
    {
        file: '{$fileFLV}',
        width: {$width},
        height: {$height},
        provider: 'video',
        stretching: 'uniform',
        smoothing: 'true',
        dock: 'true'
    },
    {
        menu: 'false',
        allowfullscreen: 'true',
        allowscriptaccess: 'always',
        allownetworking: 'always',
        wmode: 'transparent'
    }
);
</script>
```

The idea is to prefer the Flash player (we have many custom skins that we would like to keep using), then fall back to HTML 5 video, and if that fails, show the JPEG with a link to the mp4 file (that seems to work as a last-ditch effort for iOS 2/3 and old browsers so they can at least play the video by launching QuickTime).

The main issues that I'm not sure how to solve right now are:

- How can I show a higher quality video in Flash? I tried using the mp4 video instead of the flv but it doesn't work and I only get sound, no video. I think Flash is supposed to support h.264 these days, but how? And do I have to use a different transcoding method for older and newer versions of Flash?
- How can I transcode the video with better quality? Right now I am using the same bitrate for all resolutions. Any chance there is a way for ffmpeg to adjust the bitrate automatically? Or can I detect and match the resolution of the uploaded video to a list of resolution -> bitrates somehow?